# Why the map is rotating even if my location is not changing

Tags: android, location, mapbox, compass-geolocation

I am developing the app using android mapbox sdk.
By the way, I have on issue.
After I called this function(setMyLocationTrackingMode(MyLocationTrackMode.TRACKING_FOLLOW)), the map is rotating even if I am not changing my location.
Would you like to tell me why it is working?
Here is my code.

```
@Override
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
    mapView.setMyBearingTrackingMode(MyBearingTracking.COMPASS);


    //...
}

public void showNewDestination(String location_name, float lat_value, float   
    long_value) 
{
    mapView.setMyLocationTrackingMode(MyLocationTracking.TRACKING_FOLLOW);
//...
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case  R.id.button:
            showNewDestination("", 12.0023, 40,0034);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the listner for `onMyLocationChange` to update when ever you are moving the `MyBearingTracking.COMPASS`.  Which would update and rotate anytime you rotate the physical device.

Did you mean to update when changing location?  See the options in the [Mapbox Android SDK 4.1.1 docs](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/api/4.1.1/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/constants/MyBearingTracking.html).

```
@Override
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
    mapView.setMyBearingTrackingMode(MyBearingTracking.GPS);  // Update on GPS, not COMPASS changes


    //...
}
```